# Android studio editor autocomplete

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete, editor

My Android Studio has changed its Autocomplete style from multi-line to one line in XML.[image] Every time I create new tag. The editor is making it in one line, not a multi-line. Which is annoying. How can I fix that issue?

Comment: In Mac, Go to Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML

 
In Windows, File -> Settings ->  Editor -> Code Style -> XML


Under `Android` tab, below the `Layout Files`, set "Wrap attributes:" `Wrap always`, check mark on "Insert line break before first attribute" and " Insert blank line before tag"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Android` and change Layout Files attributes as below:

- Wrap Attributes = Wrap Always
- Mark Insert line break before first attribute
- Mark Insert blank line before tag

  [image]